# Как предварительно загрузить все изображения в кэш пользователя?

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Когда пользователь впервые заходит на сайт, чтоб ему все изображения загрусились кэш. Как организовать сам процесс загрузки?

Comment: Зачем что-то организовывать, если изображения на открытых страницах и так будут загружаться?

Comment: мне нужно именно так

Comment: направляйте его на страницу со всеми изображениями. После загрузки всего содержимого перенаправляйте на основную страницу сайта.

Comment: а как я проверю, что у него все загрузилось?

Comment: Вы скорее всего имеете в виду изменённые копии изображений-оригиналов? Т.е. что бы оригиналы сохранились но при этом подгрузились, например, уменьшенные копии, т.н. thumbs? Иначе ваш вопрос не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 0):

Примечание: этот ответ вольный перевод  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240110/how-do-you-cache-an-image-in-javascript

Для загрузки изображения в кэш достаточно загрузить его "на клиента". После этого картинка будет доступна из кэша на любой из страниц сайта до тех пор, пока не истечет значение expire из заголовков сервера.
Короче, лучший способ кэшировать изображения - загрузить их с помощью javascript.
Например так:

```
function preloadImages(array) {
    if (!preloadImages.list) {
        preloadImages.list = [];
    }
    var list = preloadImages.list;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        img.onload = function() {
            var index = list.indexOf(this);
            if (index !== -1) {
                // remove image from the array once it's loaded
                // for memory consumption reasons
                list.splice(index, 1);
            }
        }
        list.push(img);
        img.src = array[i];
    }
}

preloadImages(["url1.jpg", "url2.jpg", "url3.jpg"]);
```

Дання функция может быть вызвана сколько угодно раз.
В оригинальном ответе также есть ссылка на вариант этой функции, которая запускается после загрузки всех ресурсов. Вариант скопированный мной работает ассинхронно после запуска ничего не дожидаясь.

Comment: блин..а вот без js как лучше бы сделать? Можно конечно как товарищ выше посоветовал: направлять пользователя на страницу со всеми изображениями. Но как в таком случае как определать загрузилась ли у него та или иная картинка?, ведь пользователь например в любой момент мог оборвать связь и часть картинок в таком случае не загрузиться.. Есть конечно одно решение у меня, но оно сложно, а я хочу как-то попроще...

Comment: @Erepaha, понимаете ли, кэширование работает на стороне клиента. А клиентский ЯП - javascript.